# Got fatal error while run this

Tags: magento2, module, orders, event-observer

I am newbie in Magento 2 and i created an event and observer
I got fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems() on null

here is my events.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
       <event name='checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'>
            <observer
                    name='Pulsestorm_HelloWorldMVVM_HelloWorld'
                    instance='Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Observer\HelloWorld'
            />
        </event>
    </config>
```

and here is my observer

```
<?php

namespace Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class HelloWorld implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $items =$order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $productIds = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $productIds[]= $item->getProductId();
    }

    //custoemr id
    $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
    echo"<pre>";print_r($customerId); exit;

    }
```

Mainly i want to get all the data of customer and product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot retrieve the order directly from the `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

As you can see from the action class, the event only includes the order id:

```
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
        ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
    );
```

Thus, I suggest you first inject `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` in your constructor:

```
protected $_orderRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepositoryInterface
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_orderRepositoryInterface = $orderRepositoryInterface;
}
```

Then you can change your `execute()` method by replacing:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

With:

```
$orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
$order = $this->_orderRepositoryInterface->get($orderIds[0]);
```

Side note: you can remove the object manager from your observer as it's not used anywhere.

Comment: Hello @Raphael First of  all thank you for replaywhere i need to place $this->_eventManager->dispatch(); Do i need to put it in my observer

Comment: @Ramkishan no no it's the code from Magento core that dispatches the `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event. It was only to show you why you can't call `getOrder()` on the event ;)

Comment: __construct() must implement interface Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface, none given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/2.1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/2.1/app/code/Pulsestorm/HelloWorldMVVM/Observer/HelloWorld.php on line 21

Comment: i got this error now

Comment: do i need to deploy static content ?

Comment: @Ramkishan see my update ;)

Comment: same error @Raphael :(

Comment: @Ramkishan works fine for me, try to remove `var/generation`

Comment: Thank you @Raphael its worling fine after removing var/generation.